# ASP.NET Webforms show confirm box to block current execution

Tags: asp.net, webforms, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

In ASP.Net Webforms for eg. in button click i have 10 lines of code. during this process say at the line of 5 i have to show some Confirm msg/modal dialog to pause current execution.
Based on input from user say if Yes then i have to continue further else i should leave the code block.

Is this possible to do with web application ?

Comment: You need to learn more man, and by using "ASAP" it's not gonna help you.

Comment: @Arief thanx for ur comment.. as per my understanding web app wont work like this.. i want to discuss this fellow developers like you and show it to my boss what can be do and what cant.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following in your javascript:

```
if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to continue?'))
{
    return;
}
```

If what you are saying is in the middle of your server side code, I don't think you can just show a popup in the middle of the execution and continue based on user input. After all, the code is being executed in the server... You would have to change your design here.

Answer (score 0):

### Sample JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function ConfirmFromUser() {
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to pause execution?')) {
            alert('Paused');
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

---

### Sample HTML

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" OnClientClick="return ConfirmFromUser();" />
```

=============
Edit: Java Script to JavaScript